# Install scrapy, encounter WARNING: The script automat-visualize is installe

Tags: python

```
  Running setup.py install for pycparser ... done
  Running setup.py install for PyDispatcher ... done
  WARNING: The script automat-visualize is installed in '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  Running setup.py install for Twisted ... done
  WARNING: The script scrapy is installed in '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

My running environment is Mac
And then:

```
scrapy startproject douban
-bash: scrapy: command not found
```

May I ask where my problem appears and how to solve it?

Comment: You apparently need to add `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin` to your path. You may wish to Google how to do this with whatever version of MacOS you are currently running.

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Comment: Your welcome. Not a problem. =)